# Ajax get Date in dd/mm/yyyy format with xml

Tags: jquery, xml

hello people need your help in this problem please

**i have this xml**

```
<holidays >
<holiday>
<type>personal</type>
<name>AA</name>
<date>
<year>2020</year>
<month>1</month>
<day>1</day>
</date>
</holiday>
```

**and this is my ajax**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#b1").click(function () {
                var flag=false;
        $.ajax({
            type:"get",
            dataType:"xml",
            url:"Holiday.xml",
            success:function(xml){
                $(xml).find("holiday").each(function (){
                    if($(this).find("name").text()==$("#t1").val()){
                        $("#t2").val($(this).find("type").text());
                        $("#t3").val($(this).find("year/month/day").text());
                        flag=true;
                    }
                });


        </script>
</head>
<body>
    Holdiday Name:<input type="text" id="t1" /><input type="button" id="b1" value="SEARCH" /><br />
    Holdiay Type:<input type="text" id="t2" /><br />
    Holiday Date:<input type="text" id="t3" /><br />


</body>
</html>
```

**my problem is how i can call the date in year/month/day from xml to ajax**

```
 $("#t3").val($(this).find("year/month/day").text());
```

**i did this but did not work pls help and thank you **

---

```js
let xml = `<holidays >
  <holiday>
    <type>personal</type>
    <name>AA</name>
    <date>
      <year>2020</year>
      <month>1</month>
      <day>1</day>
    </date>
</holiday>`;

$(xml).find("holiday").each(function (){
  let $holiday = $(this);
  let type = $holiday.find("type").text();
  let year = $holiday.find("date year").text();
  let month = $holiday.find("date month").text();
  let day = $holiday.find("date day").text();
  console.log(type, year, month, day);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

i can not put them in the same page ...this actually web site has xml file and html file i shpuld call the xml in the html   should be d assignment

Comment: You've copied my answer into the question and said it isn't working, but I can clearly see `personal 2020 1 1` when I click on *Run code snippet*. My answer was not meant to be a ready to copy+paste fix for your application but a self-contained sample. If something needs further explanations please ask.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) expects a CSS selector, not an XPATH expression; even if it did, with `"year/month/day"` you aren't even providing the correct nesting because year, month and day are all at the same level.

```js
let xml = `<holidays >
  <holiday>
    <type>personal</type>
    <name>AA</name>
    <date>
      <year>2020</year>
      <month>1</month>
      <day>1</day>
    </date>
</holiday>`;

$(xml).find("holiday").each(function (){
  let $holiday = $(this);
  let type = $holiday.find("type").text();
  let year = $holiday.find("date year").text();
  let month = $holiday.find("date month").text();
  let day = $holiday.find("date day").text();
  console.log(type, year, month, day);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```